# What control character required for enter(return) in socket resource?

Tags: php, sockets, control-characters

I want to put enter(carriage return) in telnet socket resource.

\r is not working. Please suggest how to do enter so that command will be fired in the socket.

like `show version` is a command that i want to execute on cisco switch.
show version\r is not working.

Note: Socket is properly opened, problem is only with \r

```
$this->socketResource = fsockopen($this->nodeIp,$this->portNumber);
fputs($this->socketResource,'show version\r');
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that `\n`, `\r`, `\t` etc. will work only in double quotes

Comment: Thanks a lot, now working. Please post in answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always put `\n`, `\r`, `\t` etc. in double quotes.